# Validator for int max value validation

Tags: angular

I'm interested if and how can we add a validator for a field that is going to be saved as an int in the database? I know that I can add a max length validator, but how can check if the value of an input field does not exceed the max value of an integer? Does angular have something built it for this kind of check?

Comment: https://angular.io/api/forms/Validators#max

Answer (score 0):

You can use angular core validator to validate max value of your control and for floating number it is needed to write custom one:

```js
control = new FormControl(1, [
    Validators.max(100), 
    ({value}) => value % 1 ? {float: true} : null
  ]);
```

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-cqp3qc